# jQuery adding HTML element using before()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {
    console.log("clicked");

    $(this).before('<lable>'+ current +'.</label><input type="text", id="option"><br>');
    current = nextChar(current);
    var string = $("label:last").text();
    console.log(string);
});
```

using this, I'm trying to add some HTML element. But the behavior isn't exactly what I want it to be. The result should be something like

```
<lable>c.</lable>
<input type="text", id="option">
<br>
```

but everything is wrapped inside of lable and shows

```
<lable>c.<input type="text", id="option">
<br></lable>
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: If that's your actual code, remember that you're setting the text for label:last, and the element is written as lable.

Comment: You're using variable "current" before it's defined. Or did you define it somewhere else before this logic? If so, please show it in your post.

Comment: First, try fixing those "lable" typos.

Comment: It really was the typo issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your element in a div with a certain id like `myid`

HTML:

```
<div id='myid'>
   <input type="text" id="option">
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {

    $('#myid').prepend('<lable>'+ current +'.</label>')
});
```